# Apache Mod Rewrite based on directory structure

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I currently have this md rewrite rule in the root directory of my website:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  

RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
```

What I am wanting to do is, if the first part of the directory structure is /bd/ I want it to go to a different file

for example:

```
http://domain.com/something/somethingelse
```

Will be run by index.php

whereas:

```
http://domain.com/bd/something/somethingelse
```

would run another.php

How should the mod rewrite rule look to achieve this?

Comment: You could put another `.htaccess` inside the `/bd/` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^bd/ /another.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```